# removing tuples from list (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

I want to write a function that takes as argument a list of tuples like this:

```
remove'  [ ("a", True), ("b", False), ("c", False), ("d", True) ]
```

I would like to return a list of tuples that have False as their second value, so I'd like my function to return

```
[ ("b", False), ("c", False) ]
```

Here's what I have so far but it won't load in GHCi. can anyone help me out? Thanks

```
remove' :: [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
remove' [(a,b)] = [ c | c <- [(a,b)], c `notElem` True ]
```

Comment: Your function only matches against a list with a single tuple in it (`[(a, b])`). You probably want something more general, like `remove' list = ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to match the second element of the tuples, you need to pick the second element from the tuple and compare it with `False` like this

```
remove' :: [(a, Bool)] -> [(a, Bool)]
remove' xs = [c | c <- xs, snd c == False]
```

The [`snd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:snd) function will get second element from each of the tuples and compare them with `False`. Only if they match, they will be gathered in the resulting list.

Since the second elements are booleans, you can make use of the `not` function like this

```
[c | c <- xs, (not . snd) c]
```

We can express the same wihtout the dot notation like this

```
[c | c <- xs, not(snd(c))]
```

**Note:** In your program, you have

```
remove' [(a,b)] = ...
```

it means that, it will be executed only when remove is called with a list of tuples of size `1`. You can check that like this

```
remove' :: [(a, Bool)] -> [(a, Bool)]
remove' [(a, b)] = [(a, b)]

remove' [ ("a", True), ("b", False), ("c", False), ("d", True) ]
```

will print

```
Non-exhaustive patterns in function remove'
```

It means the patterns you specified in the function definition is not covering all the possible inputs. Since we need process a list of tuples of any length, we accept it in `xs` and use it in the List Comprehension.

Comment: what does the xs mean? I usually see xs denote the end of a list

Comment: `xs` is the parameter which will have the list of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one has yet said

```
remove' = filter (not . snd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need filter and select second item in lambda:

```
filter (\x -> (snd x) == False) [("a", False), ("b", True)]
```

Response:

```
[("a",False)]
```